# how to insert single row from datagridview to Database, Linq-to-Sql

Tags: c#, linq-to-sql, datagridview, insert-update, submitchanges

I'm trying to insert a row from my datagridview to database, which is newly created. First I use ; `db.recordTable.InsertOnSubmit();`

however it requires `db.SubmitChanges();`

to make changes permanent.
However `db.SubmitChanges();`
 submits all changes on the gridview to database. But I'm encoding password section on the datagridview therefore submit fails.
 Is there anyway for me to insert only single row without submitting all changes on the datagridview ?

Answer (score 0):

Before submit changes you can track all the changed objects in the `DataContext` like this:

```
MyEntity changedEntityToSubmit; // first you need to know what is the entity you need to submit.
List<object> allChangedEntities = new List<object>(myDataContext.GetChangeSet().Inserts);
allChangedEntities.Remove(changedEntityToSubmit);

myDataContext.Refresh(RefreshMode.OverwriteCurrentValues, allChangedEntities);
```

Then:

```
myDataContext.recordTable.InsertOnSubmit(rec);
myDataContext.SubmitChanges();
```

Comment: I tried and now I can submit , but of course another problem occured. All the passwords in the database changed with encoded ones.

Comment: Then update your post and clarify what mean the `All the passwords in the database changed with encoded ones` , Or ask it in other question.